# How can i capture audio real time (from mic.) without Java /Flash

Tags: javascript, html, audio

As far as I know the only way to capture audio from user microphone at real time is by using Flash plugin (need to get user permission) or Java.

Does someone know any other way like HTML5 or JavaScript? All my program is built with HTML5 and I don't want to use another technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.getUserMedia`.

For example:

```
(function(){
  getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
  getMedia(
    {
      video: false,
      audio: true
    },
    function (localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        //deal with data
      };
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
    }
  );
})();
```

See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia) for more info.

Note: This only works in Chrome, recent Firefox (20+), and Opera (12+), but not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: thank's - But i will Focus my Request. 
Is there any way to capture audio by Using JavaScript only?

Comment: @user2026935 I've added a code snippet which doesn't require any HTML - just JavaScript.

Comment: @user2026935 I've put the code into the answer. Did you reload it?